# does Windows OS or other known software, other than shredder, write data to disk outside of file system protocol?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, filesystems

As far as I understand it is possible to write directly to disk on Windows, bypassing the file system, and presumably this is precisely what disk shredder software does in order to shred empty space on disk. Similarly SQL Server probably does direct writing to disk within the confines of its MDF data files.

Now, does Windows OS or any other known major software (other than shredder) write data to disk outside of legit Windows files, e.g. in order to create its own quasi file system in disk sectors which, from the standpoint of Windows file system, are "unused free space"?

I guess I am primarily interested in this with regards to Windows itself because that would have important implications for any work having to do with monitoring or imposing lock down on OS activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows routinely writes to the disk MBR or more modern boot data structures, which is outside any file system. Also, file 
system initialization itself of course requires raw disk access. Windows creates a backup of the NTFS boot record at the end
of the file system partition, but outside the file system. Other than that, there would be no reason for the OS to be
accessing the disk other than through the file system. Raw disk access is limited by later Windows OS as described at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. Any locking down or monitoring done
to detect such raw access from within the OS is clearly going to have to be done at the kernal driver level.

Comment: thank you for informative response and interesting article. Question, so the article talks about "sectors being written to fall within a mounted file system that is locked explicitly". What does that mean, in terms of who is allowed to lock, what is locked and what is and is not allowed after lock? E.g. on my PC is file system locked? Can I lock it if I wanted to?